# HierarchicalDataTemplate does not work for UserControls

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, treeview, hierarchicaldatatemplate

I have a class `MyClass`, which inherits from `UserControl`:

```
public class MyClass : UserControl
{
    public string NodeName { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<MyClass> Children { get; set; }
    //...
}
```

and I have HierarchicalDataTemplate  for it:

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type sp:MyClass}"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Children}">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=NodeName}" />
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

In this case the `TreeView` shows only Top-level MyClass like a control, but not like a TextBlock with binding to NodeName and its children. Why is that?

If I don't inherit `MyClass` from `UserControl` everything works well.

```
 public class MyClass
 { 
     public string NodeName { get; set; }
     public ObservableCollection<MyClass> Children { get; set; }
 }
```

So how can I repair it in the first case?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use controls as your DataContext. Instead, you should separate your data from your view, meaning that you'll have two classes:

1. A UserControl which has a `TreeView` and also defines the hierarchical data template.
2. A data class `MyDataClass` which holds the data that should be used for displaying the tree.

Then, just set the `TreeView.ItemsSource` to the root `MyClass` object.

```
public class MyTreeUserControl : UserControl
{
}
```

```xml
<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type sp:MyDataClass}"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Children}">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=NodeName}" />
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

```cs
public class MyDataClass
{ 
    public string NodeName { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<MyDataClass> Children { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I need a tree where each node has its own view (UserControl) that's showing when I click on it. But in treeview I need only TextBlock whith Text.

Comment: That's what the `HierarchicalDataTemplate` is for. You can modify it to change the looks of each node based on its properties/data type.

Comment: Sorry - I am write incorrectly. I need a tree where each node has its own view (UserControl) that's showing when I click on it. But in treeview I need only TextBlock whith Text.